# How to convert existing rjs to use jQuery in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rjs

Right Now, I have rails 2 application that I'm converting into Rails 4, I'm getting problem to understand rjs structure and unable to convert into jquery

This is my rjs code.

```
page << %Q(if ($("patient_visit_detail_fee_schedule_wrapper")) {)
  replace = select_tag("patient_visit_detail[fee_schedule_id]",
       options_for_select((@procedure_code ? @procedure_code.procedure_codes_fee_schedule_labels.active.map{|fs| [fs.fee_schedule_label.label, fs.id]} : []), ((@procedure_code and !@procedure_code.default_fee(@patient_case).nil?) ? @procedure_code.default_fee(@patient_case).id : nil)),
       :onchange => "feeScheduleChanged(this.value)"
  ).gsub(/[\n\r]/, "")

  page << %Q($("patient_visit_detail_fee_schedule_wrapper").set("html", '#{replace}'))
page << "}"

fee = @procedure_code.default_fee(@patient_case)
unless fee.nil?
  amount = fee.fee_in_dollars || 0.to_money
  page.call("$('patient_visit_detail#{@element_suffix}_amount_in_dollars').set", 'value', amount.to_s)
end
```

I'm really stuck on how I would go about keeping the same functionality. How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Thanks In Advance.